# Filtering rows with closely related words in a column in a large dataset using the stringdist package using R

Tags: r

I am encountering memory issues in R while attempting to filter closely related words in a large dataset using the **stringdist package**. see my code:

```
# Function to filter out closely related words for a specific column
filter_related_words <- function(cleaned_data8.1, column_name, threshold = 2) {
  # Get the column values
  column_values <- cleaned_data8.1[[column_name]]

  # Compute string distances
  distances <- stringdist::stringdistmatrix(column_values, column_values)

  # Create a logical matrix for values below the threshold
  close_words_matrix <- distances <= threshold

  # Sum the logical matrix column-wise
  close_word_counts <- colSums(close_words_matrix)

  # Filter rows where there are closely related words
  filtered_data <- cleaned_data8.1[close_word_counts > 1, ]

  return(filtered_data)
}

# Specify the column name and threshold
column_name <- "nval_new"
threshold <- 0.5

# Filter closely related words for the specified column
filtered_data <- filter_related_words(cleaned_data8.1, column_name, threshold)

# View the filtered data
print(filtered_data)
```

I'm using the stringdist::stringdistmatrix function to calculate string distances, and I'm facing a "cannot allocate vector of size" error.

I appreciate any insights or guidance.

See the error code below

```
    > # Filter closely related words for the specified column
    > filtered_data <- filter_related_words(cleaned_data8.1, column_name, threshold)
    Error: cannot allocate vector of size 57.7 Gb
```